# Delay boolean changing in Laravel Livewire / PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I would like to toggle a boolean after a couple of seconds. I originally thought I could set the boolean to be true (showing the toast) and then `sleep(2)` and then set the boolean to false again. But all that occurs is (apparently) the sleep is ignored and the boolean is toggled true then immediately false, so you don't even see it appear.

Could anyone shed some light on how / why this occurs and how to overcome it ***without the use of JavaScript toast alternatives***?

```php
public function store()
{
    $this->validate();
    $this->fileref->save();
    $this->show_toast = true; # Toast show
    sleep(2); # Wait...
    $this->show_toast = false; # Toast hide
}
```

[image: boolean toggled toast notification]

Comment: Javascript toast handler is attached to the backend answer. It doesn't matter how many times you are making `sleep` inside PHP. Why don't want to use toast callbacks for that and hide the message after 2 secs using JS? Because it is direct JS work.

Comment: It seems you are confused about the server side and the client side. This is happening on the server, all the client will see is the final value (false).

Comment: Without using JS, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution, per the opening question, not resorting to a Javascript toast library, such as `Notyf` or `Toastr`. It was not my intention to avoid the use of Javascript altogether.

With that said, by dispatching a browser event (server-side) and then adding a listener to my Component (server-side), I am able to still use mostly the server-side & a simple `@if`-wrapped notification (html) to render my toast notification, time it, then remove it.

```php
public function store()
{
    $this->validate();
    $this->fileref->save();
    $this->show_toast = true; # Toast show
    $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('fileStored');
}
```

Then, back on my Livewire Component:

```php
protected $listeners = ['eatToast' => 'hideToast'];
```

Finally, the only Javascript part:

```js
document.addEventListener('fileStored', function () {
    setTimeout(() => {
        Livewire.emit('eatToast');
    }, 5000);
});
```

Final method (inside of Livewire Component) to hide toast:

```php
public function hideToast() {
    $this->show_toast = false;
}
```